# How to avoid repeated?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, collision-detection

Good day,

I am generating some circles with colors, sizes and positions. **All of this things randomly.**

But, my problem is that I do not want them to collide, so that no circle is inside another, not even a little bit.

The logic explained in detail within the code, I would like to know why the failure and why the infinite loop.

**The important functions are:**

`checkSeparation` and `setPositions`

```js
window.addEventListener("load", draw);
 
 function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("balls"), // Get canvas
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // Context
      
  canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth; // Set canvas width
  canvas.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight; // Height
      var cW = canvas.width, cH = canvas.height; // Save in vars
      ctx.fillStyle = "#fff022"; // Paint background
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cW, cH); // Coordinates to paint
      var arrayOfBalls = createBalls(); // create all balls
      setPositions(arrayOfBalls, cW, cH);
      arrayOfBalls.forEach(ball => { // iterate balls to draw
      ctx.beginPath(); // start the paint
      ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
      ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, (Math.PI/180) * 360, false); // draw the circle
      ctx.fill(); // fill
      ctx.closePath(); // end the paint
      });
 }

 function Ball() {
  this.x = 0; // x position of Ball
  this.y = 0; // y position of Ball
  this.radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 30 - 10 + 1) + 10);
  this.color = "";
 }
 
 Ball.prototype.setColor = function(){
 for(var j = 0, hex = "0123456789ABCDEF", max = hex.length,
    random, str = ""; j <= 6; j++, random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max), str += hex[random])
    this.color = "#" + str;
 };
  
 function random(val, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * val + min); // Random number
 }
 
 function checkSeparation(value, radius, toCompare) {
   var min = value - radius, // Min border of circle
       max = value + radius; // Max border of circle
       // Why ? e.g => x position of circle + this radius it will   be its right edge 
       for(; min <= max; min++) {
       if(toCompare.includes(min)) return false;
       /*
       Since all the positions previously obtained, I add them to          the array, in order to have a reference when verifying the          other positions and that they do NOT collide.
       Here I check if they collide.

       In the range of:

       [pos x - its radius, pos x + its radius]
       */
       }
   return true;   // If they never collided, it returns true
 }
 
 function createBalls() { 
  var maxBalls = 50, // number of balls
      balls = []; // array of balls
       
     for(var j = 0; j < maxBalls; j++) { // create 50 balls
     var newBall = new Ball(); // create ball 
         newBall.setColor(); // set the ball color
         balls.push(newBall); //push the ball to the array of balls
     }
     return balls; // return all balls to draw later
 }
 
 
 function setPositions(balls, canvasW, canvasH) {
  var savedPosX = [], // to save x pos of balls
      savedPosY = []; // to save y pos of balls
  for(var start = 0, max = balls.length; start < max; start++) {
   var current = balls[start], // current ball
       randomX = random(canvasW, current.radius), // get random value for x pos
       randomY = random(canvasH, current.radius); // get random value for y pos

       if(checkSeparation(randomX, current.radius, savedPosX)) {
         current.x = randomX; // If it position, along with your radio does not touch another circle, I add the position
       } else { 
         // start--; continue;
         console.log("X: The above code causes an infinite loop");
       }
       if(checkSeparation(randomY, current.radius, savedPosY)) {
         current.y = randomY;
       } else {
         // start--; continue;
         console.log("Y: The above code causes an infinite loop");
       }
  }
 }
```

```css
body,html {
 margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="balls"></canvas>
```

Comment: `// i--; continue;`
Where did the variable `i` come from in your `setPositions` function?

Comment: vivek , was start--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you test possible collisions by means of arrays of already used x and y positions, but you never add new positions to these arrays. You also check the x and y coordinates separately, which means you are really testing a collision of a bounding box.

Two circles collide when the distance between their centres is smaller than the sum of their radii, so you could use:

```
function collides(balls, n, x, y, r) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let ball = balls[i];
        let dx = ball.x - x;
        let dy = ball.y - y;
        let dd = dx*dx + dy*dy;
        let rr = r + ball.radius;

        if (dd < rr * rr) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function setPositions(balls, canvasW, canvasH) { 
    for (let i = 0, max = balls.length; i < max; i++) {

        let ball = balls[i],
            r = ball.radius,
            maxTries = 20;

        ball.x = -canvasW;
        ball.y = -canvasH;

        for (let tries = 0; tries = maxTries; tries++) {
            let x = random(canvasW - 2*r, r),
                y = random(canvasH - 2*r, r);

            if (!collides(balls, i, x, y, r)) {
                ball.x = x;
                ball.y = y;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is reasonably fast for 50 balls, but will be slow if you have more balls. In that case, some spatial data structures can speed up the collision search.

You must also guard against the case that no good place can be found. The code above gives up after 20 tries and moves the ball outside the visible canvas. You can improve the chances of placing balls by sorting the balls by radius and plaing the large balls first.

Finally, you add one hex digit too many to your random colour. (That `for` loop, where everything happens in the loop control is horrible, by the way.)

Comment: ¿Por qué en la función aleatoria, qué haces (canvasW - 2 * r) en lugar de (canvasW - r)? , if i think that sustract the radius is already a safe position

Comment: Why do you subtract ball.x - x? ,  that will only make it more out of the canvas

Comment: Explain me, the logic in the collides function, please

Comment: (1) It seems to me that you don't want to make balls go outside the canvas. Therefore, the x position can be from x to w − x, so the random number must be x + rand(w − x − x). (2) If you want to check whether two balls collide, you must check their relative positions, which you can get by subtraction. (3) The logic for collision is described in the criterion above the code: dist(c1, c2) < r1 + r2. You can find the distance with Pythagoras: sqrt(dx² + dy²) < r1 + r2. I've rewritten that to avoid calling sqrt: dx² + dy² < (r1 + r2)². This is all basic stuff.